# SonarQube does not start windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10, sonarqube

I have a problem with start **sonarqube-8.4.2.36762** on windows 10 with JAVA JDK-15.
In Wrapper.conf I've set the right path to JDK.

This is the log:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2020.10.02 15:53:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-8.4.2.36762\temp
2020.10.02 15:53:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.10.02 15:53:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube-8.4.2.36762\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-8.4.2.36762\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-8.4.2.36762\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\sonarqube-8.4.2.36762\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
2020.10.02 15:53:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
2020.10.02 15:53:30 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2020.10.02 15:53:30 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.10.02 15:53:30 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
FATAL StatusLogger Interrupted before Log4j Providers could be loaded.
 java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:372)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.lazyInit(ProviderUtil.java:121)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.hasProviders(ProviderUtil.java:108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.unit.ByteSizeValue.<clinit>(ByteSizeValue.java:39)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.<clinit>(NetworkService.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSettings.<clinit>(TransportSettings.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.newPluginService(TransportClient.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:135)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:277)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl$MinimalTransportClient.<init>(EsConnectorImpl.java:103)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.buildTransportClient(EsConnectorImpl.java:89)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getTransportClient(EsConnectorImpl.java:74)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getClusterHealthStatus(EsConnectorImpl.java:61)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkStatus(EsManagedProcess.java:88)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:73)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.isOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:58)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler.refreshState(ManagedProcessHandler.java:220)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler$EventWatcher.run(ManagedProcessHandler.java:285)
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Is there any problem with JDK-15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem with Java 15. You [need to install Java 11](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/trying-sonarqube-for-the-first-time/31423/3) to execute the program:

> SonarQube requires Java 11 to run

For example you can download it from this [website](https://adoptopenjdk.net/).

Answer (score 0):

It also worked for me when I install JDK 11 version and remove newer JDK 16 version I installed previously(it is a must to uninstall otherwise I was still getting same error). I got the JDK 11 from [Oracle website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html)